# Excel: how to find a specific text based on countif() results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hi Stackoverflow gang.

This is my 1st question, and I promise: I tried and looked everywhere before asking here.

I need help with a function (no VBA for company restrictions) in Excel, hoping it is possible.

This is the best I can do to simplify my question.

Column A has text descriptions only

Task#1

Work in progress

completed

Task#2

asset preparation

data analysis

work in progress

completed

Task#3

yet to start

Goal is to count all the "work in progress" and report "task#" that, as the example above, is never in the same position, as it can be an array, not just a single task#

in VBA would be easy... but I can't use it.

=COUNTIF(A2:A100, "*work in progress*") & " work in progress"

report the correct numbers of completed tasks. Based on this number, I tried to find and report all the tasks# using

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Task*",A1)),"task#") but this just report a mess that I can't nest with countif() function

I tried various combination of CELL(), ROW(), MATCH() that made even my cat frustrated.

any help....?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It is very unclear what it is you want. Sample data and expected result would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula to B1 and copy & paste along the way down:

`=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="Task",A1,"")`

Also enter this formula to C1 and copy & paste along the way down:

`=IF(A1="work in progress",B1&"-"&"work in progress","")`

Then you will have a view like below:

[image]

Comment: That's make completely sense as I can hide those columns... neat!! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lippa and welcome to SO. If someone provides an answer you choose to use, this it's considered courteous to mark as answered. It gives the person who answered (and gave you some of their time for free) some reputation points. It also tells the rest of us you have your answer.